# Error on HQL subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I'm running this query with a subselect inside WHERE clause

```
    select  prot.id as id,
            prot.nrProtocolo as nrProtocolo,
            prot.nrAno as nrAno,
            prot.cdSituacaoProtocolo as cdSituacaoProtocolo,
            prot.palavraChave as palavraChave,
            prot.dsObs as dsObs,
            prot.dataCriacao as dataCriacao,
            partAtual as participanteAtual,
            assunto.id as assunto_id,
            assunto.nmAssunto as assunto_nmAssunto,
            tema.id as assunto_tema_id,
            tema.nmTema as assunto_tema_nome
    from Evento evt
    inner join evt.protocolo prot
    left outer join prot.assunto assunto
    left outer join assunto.tema tema
    inner join prot.participanteAtual partAtual
    where (
            (prot.participanteSubscritor.id = :participanteId and :participanteId is not null) or
            (upper(prot.nmSubscritor) like :nmParticipante and :nmParticipante is not null ) or
            (prot.participanteEmissor.id = :participanteId and :participanteId is not null) or
            (upper(prot.nmEmissor) like :nmParticipante and :nmParticipante is not null ) or
            (
                select count(*) from ParticipanteProtocoloEntity pp where pp.protocolo.id = prot.id and
                ( 
                    (pp.participante.id = :participanteId and :participanteId is not null) or
                    (upper(pp.nmParticipante) like :nmParticipante and :nmParticipante is not null) > 0
                )
            )
          )
          and trunc(prot.dataCriacao) >= trunc(:periodoInicial) and trunc(prot.dataCriacao) <= trunc(:periodoFinal)
          and prot.cdSituacaoProtocolo <> 4
          and prot.cdSituacaoProtocolo <> 8
          and (prot.snExcluido is null or prot.snExcluido != 'S')
    order by prot.dataCriacao desc, prot.nrProtocolo asc
```

But i receive this error:

```
Error in named query: 
Protocolo.recuperaListaProtocoloPorEncaminhadoParticipanteTrans: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query
```

When i remove the subselect the query works normally.

I cannot discover what is wrong with this part:

```
(
    select count(*) from ParticipanteProtocoloEntity pp where pp.protocolo.id = prot.id and
                ( 
                    (pp.participante.id = :participanteId and :participanteId is not null) or
                    (upper(pp.nmParticipante) like :nmParticipante and :nmParticipante is not null) > 0
                )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are getting a count of `ParticipanteProtocoloEntity`. But it looks malformed to me:

```
(UPPER(pp.nmParticipante) LIKE :nmParticipante AND :nmParticipante IS NOT NULL) > 0
```

looks like `{boolean statement} > 0` to me. Im guessing you wanted the `count(*)` to be greater than zero:

```
 (
 SELECT
     COUNT(*)
 FROM
     ParticipanteProtocoloEntity pp
 WHERE
     pp.protocolo.id = prot.id
 AND ((
             pp.participante.id = :participanteId
         AND :participanteId IS NOT NULL)
     OR  (
             UPPER(pp.nmParticipante) LIKE :nmParticipante
         AND :nmParticipante IS NOT NULL ))) > 0
```